# Can't connect to mySQL because the server time zone value 'GMT Summer Time' is unrecognized

Tags: mysql, eclipse, mysql-connector

I am trying create a connection to mySQL 8.0 with mySQL connector Java 8.0.17 and the following error is preventing it:

> Java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'GMT Summer Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

I have seen similar errors with UTC time zone but haven't come across any errors with GMT time zone. What could i put into the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `serverTimezone` attribute to your jdbc URL with the value of the servers timezone. eg:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?serverTimezone=GMT
```